# The danger of "amplifying noise"

Tags: statistics

A data scientist cautioned me against "just amplifying noise" in a data analysis. What did he mean? Can you explain and/or point to resources explaining the problem?

Comment: This is a rather broad- can you give a bit more context- was he for example speaking of small count numbers in variables?
Example: Number of photons measured O ~ 10?
In such cases large relative changes can be very common. 
However, depending on the algorithm, you might overtrain on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little information in this question. I will try to answer this in the most generic sense. **Let's start by defining Noise.** Noise here as you probably know is unwanted data. Any data which you are not looking for while evaluating a problem or scenario can be considered as noise.

**Examples for amplifying noise:**
Amplifying noise might occur in cases and scenarios where there is a small data set and you are trying to supersample the dataset or another example could be while working with waveforms. In order to detect weaker signals.

**Disadvantages of Amplifying noise**
The biggest disadvantage of amplifying noise from a data science perspective is that the model used to perform various operations on the data such as Regression, Classification etc will be less efficient. For example having noise based on supersampling in Classification may affect the model. If we were to use decision trees for classification you might create a bias in the algorithm which just pertains to noise while training. So your accuracy for classification also decreases. Similarly, in regression when you train with noise you might choose a wrong model because the noise alters the goodness of the fit.